# Rails3 devise / omniauth - password_required? and form_for :validate => true don't work together

Tags: validation, devise, omniauth, form-for

I'm using devise, omniauth and client-side-validation like described in ryan bates railscasts.

I'm now facing a problem with the password validation which should be omitted when registering via omniauth 3rd party provider.

**Registration form (html.erb):**

> ### Sign up
>
> #### Register
>   via 3rd party networks
>
> <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>
>   registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
>
> #### Register directly
>
> <%= f.label :firstname %> <%=
>   f.text_field :firstname %>
>
> <%= f.label :lastname %> <%=
>   f.text_field :lastname %>
>
> <%= f.label :email %> <%=
>   f.text_field :email %>
>
> <%= f.label :password %> <%=
>   f.password_field :password %>
>
> <%= f.label
>   :password_confirmation %> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation
>   %>
>
> <%= f.submit "Register now", :class => "button-big" %>
>
> <% end %>

**My user model has a - see UPDATE below**

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation =>true
```

**clause and the password_required? definition**

```
def password_required?
(authentications.empty? || !password.blank?)
end
```

When I'm registering via omniauth 3rd party provider the registration form correctly pops up and the user is asked to enter an email address. Unfortunately the user has to enter a password although he shouldn't be prompted due to registration via 3rd party.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to accomplish?

Thanks and best regards

Jan

UPDATE: to give a more specific view I added some more code snippets

## AuthenticationsController:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
def index
@authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
end

def create
omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
if authentication
flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
elsif current_user
current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
redirect_to authentications_url
else
user = User.new
user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
if user.save
flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
else
session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
end

def destroy
@authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
@authentication.destroy
flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
redirect_to authentications_url
end

end
```

RegistrationsController:
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
def create
super
session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? 
end

private
def build_resource(*args)
super
if session[:omniauth]
@user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
@user.valid?
end
end

end
```

User Model:
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # associations
    has_many :authentications

```
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
:validatable, :email_regexp =>  /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

# validations
validates :firstname, :presence => true
validates :lastname, :presence => true

validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates_email :email

validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation =>true            

# omniauth reference 3rd party
def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
if self.firstname.blank?
self.firstname = omniauth['info']['first_name'].presence || omniauth['info']['name'].presence || " "
end

if self.lastname.blank?
self.lastname = omniauth['info']['last_name'].presence || omniauth['info']['name'].presence || " "
end

if self.email.blank?
self.email = omniauth['info']['email'].presence
end

authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
end

# omit validation for omniauth session
def password_required?
(authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
end

end
```

Authentication Model
    class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
    # associations
    belongs_to :user

```
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model  
attr_accessible :user_id, :provider, :uid
end
```

While debugging I found out that the 'authentications.build()' in the 'apply_omniauth(omniauth)' method produces an empty object, so that the 'password_required?' is always be true and a password must be provided.

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:
why does 'authentications.empty?' always return 'false'?

Thanks in advance

Jan

Comment: This question is in serious need of editing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the password_required? method should be defined like this:

```
def password_required?
  (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
end
```

Then, in your view, you should wrap your password fields like this:

```
# app/views/registrations/new.html.erb
<% if @user.password_required? %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller or model, when creating an authentication method for the first time, you should use **build** and not create or new because that way `authentications.empty?` will return true and you'll be asked to enter a password.

Finally, as for validations, you should take a look at the [client_side_validations' wiki](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Custom-Validators) about custom validations. You'll probably need to override the password validation.

Comment: Hi Ashitaka, thanks for your reply. You where right I forget the && super clause in the user model. And yes I'm trying devise, omniauth and client_side_validation (all implemented following the railscasts of ryan bates) together. - I figured out that my problem is in the user model, creating a user from 3rd party network e.g. twitter when calling apply_omniauth(omniauth). The authentications.build seems not to work. Currently I'm investigating why this happens.

Comment: SOLVED ! - I solved the issue why a new user registered via 3rd party was not created. In my user model I had validations for certain fields: firstname, lastname, email, password -> after deleting the code everything works fine now! - @Ashitaka you were right with the validations this seems to cause my problems! Thanks